# Why does speed increases when updating datetime column with index

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, ado.net, indexing

I have a SQL Server 2014 CTP2 database with a table with a `datetime` column called `ExpirationDate` that has a non-unique, non-clustered index.

The index creation statement is:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_ExpirationDate ON my_table (ExpirationDate);
```

My C# application (self-hosted WCF service) uses `ADO.NET` for select & update queries for `my_table` table.

I created a test application that performs the following scenario:

1. `SELECT` one item from database

   SELECT TOP (1) ID, ExpirationDate, ...
   FROM my_table WITH (nolock)
   WHERE Status = 1 AND ...
   ORDER BY my_table.ExpirationDate ASC
2. Change the item in the test application

   item.Status = 2;
   item.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
3. `UPDATE` the item in the database

   UPDATE my_table
   SET ExpirationDate = @ExpirationDate, Status = 2, ...
   WHERE (my_table.ID = @ID);

I have two cases in my application:

1. Change `ExpirationDate` in test application before database update
2. Not change `ExpirationDate` in test application before database update

I run the test application with 10000 items in database and the results show that the first case is 4x faster than the second.

Can anybody please explain why there is such a huge performance gain if the `datetime` column with the `index` is updated?

Comment: because the index is being used.... lol

Comment: What do you mean by "Change ExpirationDate before database update" - I'm reading that as `UPDATE ExpirationDate ...` before `UPDATE ExpirationDate...`

Comment: @RowlandShaw I added the application code that "Change ExpirationDate before database update".

Comment: Incomprehensible question.

Comment: I'm having a tough time telling what you're talking about.

Comment: We need to see more of your code - it's not clear what you're doing.

Comment: I don't think that the performance of update will go down if you remove the index. It seems that the main problem of your select is in WHERE part and we don't see it.

Comment: @user907246 I tried removing the index and then the SELECT is extremly slow (because of the ORDER BY). The other conditions in WHERE are not a problem, they are all checks on FOREIGN KEYs.

Comment: I was talking about the update. If index was helping an update to be faster your update would also slow down. But I don't think that it would be the case. As I see it your update is based on the ID field which I may guess is clustered index. So that is why its so fast vs your select. Which has a very complicated where. But withou seeing the full code I'm only guessing. Can you add the hole SELECT query for us to see? Also actual execution plan would be a nice thing to see.

Comment: Does this come down to an `UPDATE` statement which adjusts a variety of values being *slower* than an `UPDATE` statement which adjusts those same values but *also* an indexed datetime? You want to know why also changing the datetime suddenly speeds up the `UPDATE`? Is the structure of the `UPDATE` SQL the same in both cases, differing only in whether the value of the datetime is different?

Comment: @RileyMajor Yes, the `UPDATE` that updates the datetime is faster that the one that doesn't. Again yes, I want ot know why  changing the datetime speeds the `UPDATE`. And yes, the structure of the `UPDATE` SQL is the same, only the value of the datetime is diferent.

Comment: I would suggest getting both versions of the actual `UPDATE` statements and running them in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) with "Include Actual Execution Plan" (control-M) selected. Then you can examine whether there is any difference in execution plans or estimated costs. If there isn't, perhaps it's a testing fluke, or perhaps there's something else going on.

Comment: Maybe the second run is faster because data pages are loaded into memory. Try to flush the cache using "DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS" before a benchmark to have consistent results.